# Clipping using ArcPy gives ERROR 000732

Tags: arcpy, clip, batch, error-000732

I have 30 shapefiles, each of which I want to be clipped with another 3850 shapefiles (contain only one polygon). I know I need a loop in Python and use ArcPy. But I'm very new to Python.
Here's my code but I got error:

> ERROR 000732: Clip Features: Dataset
> C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme
> does not exist or is not supported
>
> Failed to execute (Clip).

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# setting my source and target geodatabase 
SourceWorkspace = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Results"
TargetWorkspace = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing"

#setting my clip feature (which is a polygon)
clipfeature = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme\*.shp"

env.workspace = SourceWorkspace

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fclist:
    outClipFeatureClass = os.path.join(TargetWorkspace, "clip area_" + fc)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,clipfeature,outClipFeatureClass)
```

Comment: So you have two groups of shapes. Do you mean each of 30 shapefiles need to be clipped by all other 3850 ones?

Comment: `clipfeature` parameter that you've passed to `Clip_analysis` should be a shapefile ends with `.shp` but it is a `url` I guess.

Comment: yes, I need another list for Clip feature because I have 3850 shapefiles. but I don't Know how can do this?

Comment: Second argument passed to `Clip_analysis` should be a shapefile ends with `.shp` but `clipfeature` is a `url`.

Comment: Wildcards are not legal in nearly every function within ArcPy. You always need to use a list function and iterate (wildcards are only valid in list functions).

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like the path to a polygon feature class:

```
clipfeature = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme"
```

It should maybe a feature class in a file geodatabase:

```
clipfeature = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme.gdb\polygons123"
```

or a shapefile:

```
clipfeature = r"C:\Users\Farzane\Desktop\Master97\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme.shp
```

Comment: In fact, this is a path to the folder containing the shapefiles needed for the clip feature classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute `clip analysis` multiple time for each of 30 shapefiles, do something as follow:

```py
import os
import glob
import arcpy
    
# setting my source and target geodatabase 
src_dir= r"\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\source"
des_dir = r"\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\target"
    
#setting my clip feature (which is a polygon)
clippers_dir = r"\GNOMEmodeling\Postprocessing\Ropme"
    
arcpy.env.workspace = src_dir
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
clippers = [glob.glob(f) for f in [clippers_dir + '/*.shp']]

for fc in fclist:
    src_file_dir, src_file_name = os.path.split(clipper)
    for clipper in clippers:
        clipper_dir, clipper_name = os.path.split(clipper)
        clipper_name = src_file_name.split('.')[0] + "_" + clipper_name 
        output_dir = os.path.join(des_dir , clipper_name)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,clipper,output_dir)
```

Please remember `Clip_analysis` is executed once and accepts two shapefiles. Therefore you will have `30*3850` individual clipped shape files when it finishes.

Comment: I have the merged shapefile which contains 3850 polygons but I need to clip them individually with 30 other shape files and then perform another operation.
However, thanks for your first code, it is very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117729/discussion-between-arashmad-and-vince).

Comment: I ran the last code you sent and got an error. I think I should update fclist with the replace command. But I do not know how?                                                                     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: No, because I haven't 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network. how can I fix it?

Comment: thanks, my problem is solved.

Comment: By answering your own question, you could gain reputations which provide you with more services. Moreover it may be other's question. @FarzaneHashemi